# How does for loop print all the line of a text file without using readline()

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I'm studying the file section and I'm confused by the code below.

```
def printAllLines(fileObject):
        for line in fileObject:
                 print(line, end = "")
```

In this case, does one iteration of a line equal one line of the original text file?

Is there any index in a text file?

Can I think of a pure text file as a list that contains multiple items?

And each item contains a line of text?

Comment: It's confusing the first time you see it, but it's incredibly useful.  Any Python object can display special behavior when you iterate through it.  For Lists and Tuples, we show an item at a time.  For file objects, the decision was made that iterating through it shows one line at a time.

Comment: A text file is also a so-called "iterator" which can return content line by line if asked e. g. by a for-loop. Each open file has a file pointer to define where next read or write should happen.

Comment: Oops. To fully answer your question.  There is no index.  A line ends with a newline character.  Python is pretty much reading characters (efficiently) until it sees a newline character and calling what it gets a "line" and returning that.

Answer (score 0):

A file object created through the `open()` function in Python is an object that contains each line of the file. For a text file, it is a `typing.TextIO` object; if this were a binary file, it would be `typing.BinaryIO`. This object is iterable but cannot be indexed, as it does not define `___getitem___`.

TL;DR: You can think of indexing a file using a `for` loop as syntactic sugar; you can cut down on lines using it, but don't think about it too hard.

To answer each of your questions:

- Yes, each iteration of `line in fileObject` is one line of the text file.
- No, you cannot index a text file without readline() or another function. You can't do `fileObject[1]`, for example.
- Don't think of it like this. Think of this format of indexing a file as a useful trick.

Hopefully this fully answers your question.